# Elasticsearch curator purge s3

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, elasticsearch-curator

I'm using curator(version 3.5.1) to perform daily backup on a S3 bucket. I found the way to automatically delete index in my ElasticSearch cluster but is it possible to automatically delete s3 backup which are older than 15 days without deleting them in the ES Cluster?

Currently my curator command:

```
curator --host elastic-prod snapshot --request_timeout 7200 --repository s3.prod.backup.elasticsearch --skip-repo-validation indices --all-indices
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you not able to use the Curator delete snapshots sub-command?

Comment: when I've tried, curator has deleted the index in ElasticSearch but not in S3.  And if I set lifecycle rules on my S3 bucket content to automatically delete files older than 15 days, do you think it can work? I'm not sure with this method because maybe I'll delete some "important" files for Elasticsearch or Curator...

Answer (score 0):

Not without causing Elasticsearch some grief. The API should be used to delete snapshots so Elasticsearch can keep proper track of them.

Comment: When you said the API, it's the Elasticsearch API which I need to call? Do you have an example?